# What should I have flagged this post as?

Tags: discussion, flagging

[The post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/150394/31051) pictured below was ultimately deleted.

I flagged it as spam ("*irrelevant or unsolicited messages sent over the Internet, typically to a large number of users*") although this was rejected as no evidence was found for it.

**What should I have flagged this as?**

---

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### First off, it's not spam

It's worth pointing out that the spam flag (and also the "abusive/offensive" flag) carries some [additional penalties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/276025), so you shouldn't use it unless the post you're flagging is *actually* spam, which on SE is defined to be:

> Exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's affiliation.

### I'd have raised a custom moderator flag

There is, in fact, a very low quality flag for questions (I can flag this question as VLQ, for instance), but there are [several](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209302/276025) conditions [under which](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244717/276025) it is not available<sup>1</sup>, so you couldn't use it in this case. In this case, assuming your intent is to have the post deleted, the best course of action would have been to raise a custom flag with a message along the lines of:

> This question serves no useful purpose and should be deleted.

If you just wanted the question closed, you could also have flagged it for closure using any relevant reason:

- **Off-topic**, which it obviously is
- **Unclear what you're asking** which, since there wasn't a question at all, certainly applies. Worth noting is that the question *was* closed under this reason before it was deleted

---

<sup>1</sup> One of these conditions appears to be "has ever had a close vote on it"; notice that you can't flag [Can werecoyotes/werejaguars form packs?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/149555/31051) as VLQ, which has already gone through the close votes queue

Comment: "*Unfortunately, we don't have a "Very Low Quality" flag for questions*" - [yes we do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTtbE.png), provided (I think) the question doesn't have a positive score.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Yes, I've been doing more research. It doesn't appear on questions that are closed or are in the close votes queue, which this one likely was

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know that a question couldn't be flagged as VLQ if it's already in the CV review queue. Could it be that that's an SO-specific thing, since the main meta post you link to is about the Triage review queue?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Ask Shog; I don't know

Answer (score 5):

On Stack Exchange, "spam" has a very specific meaning:

[image: spam]

Don't flag a question as spam unless it's specifically *promotional content*. Spam flags carry additional penalties which shouldn't be applied to non-spam posts.

For [this particular question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/150394/31394) (link only visible to 10k+ users), you could have done any one of a number of things (in decreasing order of desirability):

- flagged it as **should be closed** (note: for users with >3k rep, this amounts to a close vote)
- flagged it as **very low quality** (which I believe sends the post into the Low Quality Posts review queue as *well* as the Close Votes one, making it likely to be closed even more quickly)
- used a **custom moderator flag** and typed an explanation of what the problem with the post is.

Note that custom mod flags usually *shouldn't* be used for questions which simply need to be closed. If you find a blatantly off-topic question, flag it for closure, or possibly as "very low quality" if appropriate; but **moderator intervention isn't usually required**. Five 3k+ rep users are enough to close any question; once it's been closed, three 20k+ rep users are enough to delete it right away, but even that isn't usually necessary - after a certain number of days, questions which are closed, downvoted, and unanswered will be cleaned up by the system anyway.

Comment: There is however no "Very Low Quality" Flag on a question, further, would it have been valid to use the "Off Topic" or "Unclear What You're Asking" flags?

Comment: @Edlothiad Yes, those are two of the options you'll see when selecting "should be closed" on the flag menu.

Comment: but would those two have been valid?

Comment: @Edlothiad Sure. As Jason says, it *is* clearly off-topic and unclear what's being asked. (Note that "should be closed" flags are never handled by moderators - they send a post to the Close Votes review queue, and are marked helpful as soon as a 3k+ user votes to close.)